# Use localstorage in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am trying to use localstorage in my application.The idea is in two pages.One online page that retrieve data from server when available and saves it to local storage, and one offline page that get this information from localstorage when the connection is not available.Here is my code:

My model: SProductModel.js

```
Ext.define('App.wms.SProductModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty:'noId',
fields: ['cost','count','id','product_code','title'],

});
```

My Store: SProductStore.js

```
Ext.define('App.wms.SProductStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'App.wms.SProductModel',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'localstorage',
    id  : 'myProxyKey'
}

});
```

Online Page: online.js

```
var sproductstore = new App.wms.SProductStore;
this.stationProducts.store.each(function(item){
    sproductstore.add(item);
})
sproductstore.sync();
```

Offline Page: offline.js

```
var sproductstore = new App.wms.SProductStore;
console.log(Ext.getStore('sproducts'));
```

But in the second page output of console.log(Ext.getStore('sproducts')) is an empty store.can anyone help to correct it or show me the right path?

UPDATE:

I replaced the line sproductstore.sync(); with sproductstore.sync({callback: function(){console.log("sync")}}); and found out that sync does not execute at all.

Comment: Try adding `storage` listener to the `window` and reload the store in `offline.js`.

Comment: Maybe the sync may not have been executed because there was nothing in `stationProducts` store. You can see in [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/b22) demo that sync is executed only first time.

Comment: Thank you Bojan.i figured it out.the problem was due to "id" field in my model.i renamed it and now it's working fine